# Bash memorize value between two script occurrence

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, conditional-statements

I would like to execute a simple script which contains a function define as :

```
#!/bin/bash

function procedure()
{
   if [ var1 -eq 0 ]; then
   ... do some stuff 
   var1=1
   fi 

   do some other things ..
 }

 procedure
```

- first occurrence : ./script.sh
  I would like to execute the instructions defined into the if condition.
- Second occurrence : ./script.sh
  I would like only execute the instructions defined outside the if condition but the var1=1 will not be memorized, isn't ?

Is it possible in bash ?

It should be possible by creating a temporary file or something else but I guess there is a more efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

If you run with the same environment `var1` will be the same.

Just run:

```
$ source script.sh
$ echo $var1 # verify value
$ source script.sh
```

Comment: Oh thank for this advice ! It works but an other requirement is that I have to call the script without "source" before name. Create a file is the only one solution

Answer (score 0):

Just pass an argument to your script to control the behavior:

```
#!/bin/bash

procedure() {
   if [[ "$1" -eq 0 ]]; then
     ... do some stuff 
     var1=1
   fi 

   do some other things ..
 }

 procedure "$1"
```

And use it as:

```
./script.sh 1
./script.sh 0
```

Comment: Yes it could be a good solution ! However I can't pass an argument to the script because it will be executed by a background process on which I can not make modification

Comment: Hmm in that case creating temporary file is the only thing I can think of.

Comment: It was my first idea but I would have found a more easy way